# Added a misspelling to the dictionary in One Note 2016

Tags: microsoft-onenote-2016

I've accidentally added a misspelled word to the dictionary in One Note 2016 (Operating System: Windows 10). Where do I go to remove the misspelling from One Note's dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One Note 2016 seems to use the Windows 10 dictionary. To fix the misspelling I went to: '%AppData%\Microsoft\Spelling\' picked my language ('en-US' in my case). I then opened the default.dic file with Notepad and removed the misspelled entry.